# WebdriverIO not submitting the dropdown after selecting an item

Tags: javascript, android, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriver-io

I am testing against a webview (Cordova hybrid app) using Webdriver.io.

I am trying to select the Month for the DOB from a dropdown menu in a form.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
console.log(`Filling birthdayMonth..`);
const dropdowns = browser.elements('#birthdayMonth');
const dropDown = dropdowns.value[0]; //.click();
dropDown.selectByIndex(4);
```

The problem is that the item is selected but the native dropdown is not submitted. (Only if I manually tap on it the month field gets populated)

How can I solve this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using:

```
const dropdowns = browser.elements('#birthdayMonth');
const dropDown = dropdowns.value[0];
dropDown.selectByValue('number:4');
```